# Why am I getting "cannot ready property of " error in this AngularJS code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have 2 interlinked functions. I am attaching a screenshot of the format of the responseData

[image: Screenshot 1]

```
function checkScenario(responseData) {
        // lines of code //
        doThisThing(responseData.tblBooking);
}


function doThisThing(data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));   // works fine
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data.tblBooking.tblVehicleType.vehicleTypeCode));   // error
        $scope.tripData = data;
        console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.tripData));  // works fine
        $scope.tripDataVehicleType = data.tblBooking.tblVehicleType.vehicleTypeCode;
        console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.tripDataVehicleType));  // error in this line

}
```

I meaning after storing the entire data passed from the previous function in $scope.tripData , I want to get the value of data.tblBooking.tblVehicleType.vehicleTypeCode. I have tried to get that data in 2 ways , directly as in last line & also by storing in a scope variable. I am getting error in both cases .

I want to implement an if block like this -
 tblBooking.tblVehicleType.vehicleTypeCode === '1'

Where I am making mistake.

Comment: can you post the result of the `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: try this   `data.tblBooking.tblVehicleType['vehicleTypeCode'] `

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @sachila ranawaka  - The console in doThisThing {"sourceLocation":{"locationName":"Metro Avenue","latitude":32.509237900000002,"longitude":71.373555,"placeId":0},"destLocation":{"locationName":"Lyons park","latitude":"32.348","longitude":"71.116","placeId":0},"tblVehicleType":{"vehicleTypeCode":"1","vehicleTypeName":"Transit"},"tblVehicleCategory":{"vehicleCatId":1,"vehicleCatDescription":"Truck","vehicleSeatingCapacity":"40"}}

Comment: @Himesh Suthar with your suggestion same problem - Cannot read property 'tblVehicleType' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

`console.log(JSON.stringify(data.tblBooking.tblVehicleType.vehicleTypeCode));`

to this

`console.log(JSON.stringify(data.tblVehicleType.vehicleTypeCode));`

```js
 
var responseData = {"tblBooking": {
      "sourceLocation": {
          "locationName": "Metro Avenue",
          "latitude": 32.509237900000002,
          "longitude": 71.373555,
         "placeId": 0
      },
      "destLocation": {
          "locationName": "Lyons park",
          "latitude": "32.348",
          "longitude": "71.116",
          "placeId": 0
      },
      "tblVehicleType": {
          "vehicleTypeCode": "1",
          "vehicleTypeName": "Transit"
      },
      "tblVehicleCategory": {
          "vehicleCatId": 1,
          "vehicleCatDescription": "Truck",
          "vehicleSeatingCapacity": "40"
      }
  }
}

doThisThing(responseData.tblBooking); 

function doThisThing(data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));   // works fine
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data.tblVehicleType.vehicleTypeCode));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have sent the payload to second method with as `responseData.tblBooking`

```
function checkScenario(responseData) {
  // lines of code //
  doThisThing(responseData.tblBooking);
}
```

The property available here are the nested ones in `tblBooking` such as `data.tblVehicleType` like:

```
function doThisThing(data) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
   console.log(JSON.stringify(data.tblVehicleType.vehicleTypeCode)); 
   $scope.tripData = data;
   console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.tripData));
   $scope.tripDataVehicleType = data.tblVehicleType.vehicleTypeCode;
   console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.tripDataVehicleType));    
}
```